# Chrome Extension using API is not working

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

I have been going down rabbit holes the past 2 days and haven't figured this out. I'm new to coding which could be my overall problem!

My HTML code (popup.html) for my Chrome extension is as follows:

```
<html>  
   <body>

   <div id="ourmanna-verse">Loading...</div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="votd.js"></script>      </body>
</html>
```

My votd.js file code is below.

```
<script src="http://www.ourmanna.com/verses/api/js/" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

The website in the script tag has the function if you follow the url, though I'm not copying and pasting it in because of the formatting of it from the browser rendering it :O!

[image]

The popup.html file isn't pulling the votd.js file to populate in the div ID, "ourmanna-verse". Can anyone help me figure this out?

I also included the errors from the console and the code from the votd.js file. Maybe it's with the syntax of my code? 
[Console errors and .js file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGn1X.png)

Comment: The js file should be referenced using a `script` tag in html. See also the [extensions overview article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

Comment: Thanks, wOxxOm - I updated the HTML file to reflect this (updated the code /question above to show) but the HTML file still isn't calling to my .js file. Any other suggestions? I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: votd.js on the screenshot is not a valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.ourmanna.com/verses/api/js/` contains this inline script (with nice formatting):

```
(function(){
    var mannaverse='For the LORD is our judge, the LORD is our lawgiver, the LORD is our king; it is he who will save us.';
    var mannaverse_reference='Isaiah 33:22';
    var mannaverse_version='NIV';
    if(document.getElementById('ourmanna-verse')!==null){
        document.getElementById('ourmanna-verse').innerHTML='<div id="mannaverse-container"><p id="mannaverse">'+
        mannaverse+'</p><p id="mannaverse-reference">'+
        mannaverse_reference+' <small id="mannaverse-version"><i>('+
        mannaverse_version+')</i></small></p></div>';
    }
})();
```

`votd.js` contains a HTML script reference to that:

```
<script src="http://www.ourmanna.com/verses/api/js/" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

That doesn't work because `votd.js` can only contain javascript.

I'm guessing that you want the popup to call this remote JS file. For that you need to first add it directly to `popup.html`:

```
<html>  
<body>
   <div id="ourmanna-verse">Loading...</div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ourmanna.com/verses/api/js/"></script>      
</body>
</html>
```

You also need to allow access to this remote script in the content security policy in the `manifest.json`:

```
{
    ...
        "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.ourmanna.com blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource: ;object-src 'self'",
    ...
}
```

Finally you need to ensure that your source script can be served over HTTPS.

Comment: That would be impossible, as `http:` domains cannot be whitelisted.

Comment: Note that while your answer is technically flawless, for this particular purpose it's a _terrible_ solution, as they have data APIs: http://www.ourmanna.com/verses/api/ That would be much more secure than running arbitrary remote code - which may get one in trouble with Chrome Web Store.

Comment: @Xan yes, there's a place for this kind of dynamic scripting, but it's overkill for injecting bible verse into a popup. That's getting rather out of scope here though - I can tell them how to run the script that's failing and why it's failing. I don't really know enough about what they're trying to do to go any further.

Comment: @Keith, thanks for your input! I tried you solution but now getting errors on both the Chrome Extension page (where you load the unpacked extension) and in the console.

Extension Page: "These were warnings when trying to install this extension: -Ignored insecure CSP value "http://www.ourmanna.com/verses/api/js/" in direction 'script-src'.

Console: Refused to load the script 'http://www.ourmanna.com/verses/api/js/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

Comment: @JustinBertsch Yeah, that will be either due to the CSP containing an HTTP reference (as Xan commented) or your server not being HTTPS (all servers should be HTTPS these days).